# How to force SwiftData view to refresh when app is becoming foreground

Tags: swiftui, swift-data

I am modifying the stored data from an interactive widget. The changes are registered properly. However, opening the app (coming from background to foreground), the data is not updated and views show the older data.

Is there a way to force views to refresh after app becomes foreground? I believe the CoreData equivalent is `refreshAllObjects`.

Edit: I realized that this happens when the coredata entity is passed to a view after it is being Query'd. So, the view that I would like to be updated do not have the source entity which is stored at the previous view that pushes it.

Comment: Did you reload the timeline?

Comment: @lorem-ipsum The problem is not updating the widget. The problem is updating the app; widget is working as expected.

Comment: If you are using `@Model` properly, it should update automatically. Probably you need to show some code that exhibits your issue. Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76642462/16157878) helps?

Comment: @soundflix Yes, I am using `@Model` property wrapper. If I go to another view and come back, the data is updated but it is not updated otherwise after coming to foreground.

Comment: Hey @soundflix did you find a solution to this? I'm facing exactly the same problem, the relation is not getting updated unless I switch the tab and come back.